# How can I open a read only bash shell

Tags: bash, permissions

I would like to browse some files without modifying them.  I know I can avoid using certain commands, but I'm worried something could happen by accident.

Is there a way to create a bash subshell that doesn't have permission to write anything?  Something like `bash donotmakechanges`.

I figure I could make another user, but that feels like overkill.

Comment: You could mark the files as `immutable` if the filesystem they are on supports file attributes. See `chattr` and `lsattr` for ext3/4 filesystem attributes

Comment: If it were possible to "make bash read-only" what about all the other programs which might change files and can be invoked via bash? Maybe you need to think about permissions and users instead of how the shell behaves.

Answer (score 5):

You could use a bind mount to mount the directory tree read-only. You will need root access.

```
# mount -o ro --bind /home /home_ro
# cd /home_ro
# touch file
touch: cannot touch ‘file’: Read-only file system
```

Then just navigate around /home_ro instead.

Comment: Good idea.  Unfortunate that it requires extra permissions when the intended goal is basically to have fewer permissions.

Comment: @sudorm-rfslash - only the setup requires extra permissions. The actual user that you use can have the same since it is the same directories.

Answer (score 0):

```bash
sudo -u nobody bash
```

### Caveats

1. You will still have access to files accessible by every other user. For example, `everyone's` file:

   ```bash
   $ touch everyone\'s
   $ chmod 222 everyone\'s
   ```

   is still writable by `nobody`:

   ```bash
   $ sudo -u nobody touch everyone\'s
   ```
2. You will get access to files that are meant to be inaccessible by anyone. For example, `nobody's` file:

   ```bash
   $ touch nobody\'s
   $ sudo chown nobody nobody\'s
   ```

   is not writable by regular users:

   ```bash
   $ touch nobody\'s
   touch: cannot touch "nobody's": Permission denied
   ```

   but is writable by `nobody`:

   ```bash
   $ sudo -u nobody touch nobody\'s
   ```
3. User `nobody` must not be used for this purpose, as explained in https://askubuntu.com/a/674397/1086669
4. You need the permission to run `sudo`

Apart from that, it does render normally writable files read-only

```bash
$ touch mine
$ sudo -u nobody touch mine
```